# How to set HTML value attribute (with spaces)

Tags: php, html, forms

When I use PHP to set the value of a HTML form input element, it works fine provided I don't have any spaces in the data.

```
<input type="text" name="username"
<?php echo (isset($_POST['username'])) ? "value = ".$_POST["username"] : "value = \"\""; ?> />
```

If I enter "Jonathan" as the username, it is repeated back to me as expected.  If I enter "Big Ted", however, I only get "Big" repeated back when I submit the form.

Note that the `$_POST["Username"]` variable is correct; when I echo it using PHP, it is set to "Big Ted".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Quote it. Otherwise the space will just become an attribute separator and everything after spaces will be seen as element attributes. Rightclick page in webbrowser and view source. It should not look like this (also see syntax highlight colors):

```
<input value=Big Ted>
```

but rather this

```
<input value="Big Ted">
```

Not to mention that this would still break when someone has a quote in his name (and your code is thus sensitive to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) [attacks](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html)). Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Kickoff example:

```
<input value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['username']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) : ''); ?>">
```

Comment: XSS has nothing to do here. Encoding required by standard. Even if you edit fully allower HTML in the admin area, you have to htmlencode values, including textarea content.

Comment: @Col: where did I said that XSS is related to the particular problem? :)

Comment: ah yes I've overlooked it. Focused on the key word, you know :)

Comment: why there is a question mark (?) after isset function? can you please explain?

Comment: @057AhmadHilmanD: https://www.phptutorial.net/php-tutorial/php-ternary-operator/

Comment: https://www.phpspiderblog.com/?s=operator

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="text" name="username"
<?php echo (isset($_POST['username'])) ? "value = '".$_POST["username"]' : "value = ''"; ?> />
```

You have to wrap the variable result with quotes, so that the browser can know what's the content of the input.

Comment: add a quote to your name and you'll end up with same problem :)

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="username"
<?php echo (isset($_POST['username'])) ? ('value = "'.$_POST["username"].'"') : "value = \"\""; ?> />
```

Be aware of your quote usage.

Comment: add a quote to your name and you'll end up with same problem :)

Comment: @Col Shrapnel - This was a very trivial question and I'm much too used to frameworks doing the work for me to bother advising that, but sure...

Comment: Why not to bring an example with your favorite framework use then?

Comment: Because it'd be out of the scope of this simple question and just overcomplicate things.

Comment: His problem was he wasn't wrapping double quotes around a string which had a space in it ( properly coding an attribute having a value in HTML ), the solution was to wrap double quotes around it so it was valid HTML, thus answering his question. You're overly being nitpicky about something that isn't so major. Thank you for the downvote.

Answer (score 2):

As you see its not PHP5 or even PHP question at all.
Basic HTML knowledge is obligatory for one who want to be a PHP user.

And with using templates it looks way more neat:

Getting data part code:

```
$username = "";
if isset($_POST['username'])) $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["username"]);
```

And template code:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?=$username?>">
```

If you divide your code to 2 parts it become way more supportable and *readable*.

Comment: It's not a good practice to use short open tags since the server can have them disabled though, I would advise against recommending that to the OP.

Comment: @meder well just turn it on. Not a big deal. That's what configuration settings are for.

Comment: Why would you? It's a bad practice to use it in the first place. That and I wouldn't ever use PHP if I managed the server.

Comment: @meder who said it's "bad practice"?

Comment: @Col Shrapnel - Most experienced PHP developers agree it is bad practice. They're also being phased out in PHP6, are they not?. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use

Comment: @meder no, they are not being phased out in PHP6, it's empty rumor. Spreaded by these "most experienced PHP developers". I don't see one there though. ZF uses short tags in their template system if you prefer fat authority as a proof.

Answer (score 2):

just make sure you put the colon after the field for example :

```
  <option value="'.$row['name'].'">
```

Answer (score -2):

Used quotes and it worked.
On the other side, needed to use the following:

```
$param=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/','', $param);
```

Comment: That looks like it would remove some characters from the parameter but leave the spaces.  The spaces should get encoded, but this doesn't do that.