# Stopping JSTL function output with whitespaces from being rendered as different attributes

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have been trying to get the contents of the comma separated string like

```
"RAVI, PRASHANT, ANKIT, PANKAJ, Nilesh Kumar Mishra, Anoop Kumar"
```

Each element in this list needs to be displayed in the dropdown menu in a JSP page. The JSP code doing this bit goes like this:

```
<select class="style1" id="id" placeholder="sample placeholder" >
    <c:forEach var="name" items="${fn:split(names, ',')}">
        <option value="${name}">${name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

But after the page is rendered i notice that if output for ${name} contains any whitespace the words after the whitespace are getting rendered as the attributes inside option tag.

```
<select class="style1" id="id" placeholder="sample placeholder" >
    <option value="RAVI">RAVI</option>
    <option value="PRASHANT">PRASHANT</option>
    <option value="ANKIT">ANKIT</option>
    <option value="PANKAJ">PANKAJ</option>
    <option value="Nilesh" kumar="" mishra="">Nilesh Kumar Mishra</option>
    <option value="Anoop" kumar="">Anoop Kumar</option>
</select>
```

I tried some searching for the solution and came across with the SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078192/how-to-set-html-value-attribute-with-spaces-using-php). But solution provided is for the PHP and also i am unable to find the equivalent for *htmlspecialchars* in JSP.

Can anybody help me in avoiding those unintended attributes and instead get the whole string as a value for 'value' attribute in the option tag, just like the first three are getting rendered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try this: <option value="${fn:join(name, ' ')}">${name}</option> and see what happens

Comment: To escape XML special characters, an analogous JSTL function which may be supposed is `${fn:escapeXml(name)}` or while outputting, `<c:out value="${...}" escapeXml="true"/>` which is implicit (i.e. `escapeXml` is set to true, by default) but this is unlikely to help in this case. What does `names` contain, a comma-separated list of Strings for sure?

Comment: @Tiny, yes the `names` contains the comma separated list of strings like this: `"RAVI, PRASHANT, ANKIT, PANKAJ, Nilesh Kumar Mishra, Anoop Kumar"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your situation, here is probably the easiest way to deal with it ... a) replace all the spaces with |s, b) split the string,  c) replace the |s back to spaces.   Here's how to do that ...

```
<select class="style1" id="id" placeholder="sample placeholder" >
    <c:forEach var="name" items="${fn:split(fn:replace(names, ' ', '|'), ',')}">
        <option value="${fn:replace(name, '|', ' ')}">${name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

this will make sure that the split string is one continuous string, yet the output is formatted as it was originally (with spaces).

Comment: Sorry for coming back late, but this solution worked absolutely fine...thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Cool.  You can click the check on this answer to mark it solved, if it's working for you.

Answer (score 0):

I bet your comma delimited string has quotes in it when the data has a white space, like this:

```
RAVI, PRASHANT, ANKIT, PANKAJ, "Nilesh Kumar Mishra", "Anoop Kumar"
```

Then when the foreach runs the quotes are prematurely terminating the *value* attribute.  So you end up with this ...

```
<option value=""nilesh kumar mishra"" ...
```

instead of this ...

```
<option value="nilesh kumar mishra" ...
```

And the browser ends up interpreting each of those strings as an attribute instead of the data for the *value* attribute.  So you need to get rid of the quotes like this:

```
<select class="style1" id="id" placeholder="sample placeholder" >
    <c:forEach var="name" items="${fn:split(names, ',')}">
        <option value="${fn:replace(name, '"', '')}">${name}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Comment: Sorry for not including that part in the question itself but first we are declaring the string in the controller like this:

    private final String names = "RAVI, PRASHANT, ANKIT, PANKAJ, Nilesh Kumar Mishra, Anoop Kumar";

and later setting it in the model to be picked by JSP like this:

    model.addAttribute("names", names);