# form does not get full text from database

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, laravel

when i try to edit a record, my form does not receive the full text, for example, if in my database I have the string "hello world" in my edit form it will just show me "hello"
edit function

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $cooperado = Cooperado::find($id);

    return view('cooperados.edit', compact('cooperado'));
}
```

edit form

```
  <form method="post" action="{{ route('cooperados.update', $cooperado->id) }}">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Nome :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nameCoop" value={{ $cooperado->nameCoop }} />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="description">Observações :</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" value={{ $cooperado->description }} />
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Does `value={{ $cooperado->nameCoop }}` need quotes round the value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set HTML value attribute (with spaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078192/how-to-set-html-value-attribute-with-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the values should be surrounded by `"`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078192/how-to-set-html-value-attribute-with-spaces).

In your code it should be

```php
value="{{ $cooperado->nameCoop }}"
```

and

```php
value="{{ $cooperado->description }}"
```

The `"` characters tell the browser that the entire attribute value is enclosed between them. Without them, the browser doesn't know where the value ends and where the HTML attributes start.