# Not Able to Set Attribute of a Checkbox When It has Space in It's Value Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having space between string in **Value** of a **checkbox** input like `Item Two` I am not able to set the checkbox to be checked.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="item2" name="check" value="Item Two">Item Two
$(":checkbox[value=Item Two]").prop('disabled', true);
```

Is there any way to fix this without changing the value of the input?

```js
$(":checkbox[value=ItemOne]").prop("checked", "true");
$(":checkbox[value=Item Two]").prop('disabled', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" id="item1" name="check" value="ItemOne">Item One
<input type="checkbox" id="item2" name="check" value="Item Two">ItemTwo
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing the double quotes with backticks (``) and wrapping your value like `value="Item Two"`?

Comment: just put the string in quotes. `":checkbox[value='Item Two']"`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set HTML value attribute (with spaces)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078192/how-to-set-html-value-attribute-with-spaces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must quote the value if it has spaces

```
$(':checkbox[value="Item Two"]').prop('disabled', true);
```